# How can i do event listener for a custom select in the table?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have table it contains columns from database and  I have custom select on the column and also have button update. Now I need when I click on the button make event listener in custom select and get what the user selected and print the value  selected on  console using JavaScript ….How can I do this please any one help me...

```
@foreach ($bookinghalls as $item)

    <tr>
        <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
   <td >{{$item->hall_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->from_date}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->to_date}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->type_booking}}</td>  
    <td  ><select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" name="intervel"   >
@if ($item->pay==0)
<option value="0" >Not paid</option>    
<option value="1" >paid </option>

@else ($item->pay==1)
<option value="1" >paid </option>
<option value="0" >Not paid</option>
@endif
</td>
     <td id="stauts">  <?php 
        if($item->stauts==0)
         print_r("available");
     elseif($item->stauts==1)
     print_r("it's Processing ");
     elseif($item->stauts==2)
     print_r("booking done");
       ?></td>
     <td><button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary but_update"  name="imagaid"   >update</button>
     </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

for set event listener for a `<select>` tag and get value of `<option value="any-value" selected>text</option>`, do as following:

```
document.querySelector('.custom-select').addEventListener('change', function () {
    let selectedValue = this.value;
    console.log(selectedValue);
});
```